# Getting error while importing xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

import xnl.etree.ElementTree as ET

ModuleNotFoundError :No module name 'xml.etree';'xml' is not package

Comment: The package that you mentioned is included in by default in Python, so it shouldn't cause any problem. Do you have Python installed completely?

Comment: Misspelling? `xnl.etree.ElementTree` is wrong. It should be `xml.etree.ElementTree`.